# Digital Data Packets Transmission Probability Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Thanks for checking this out. I will write the question and then I'll write how I managed to solve it. Now, if someone could review the problem, and double check the solution, or provide a different approach one, that would be very helpful!

**Problem**

The digital transmission of packets is implemented with sending a sequence of ones (1) and zeros (0) bits through a data stream. It is known that a zero is 5 times more common (in occurrence) than a one. Due to lack of high-end transmission equipment and solution, the probability that a zero will be received as one (corrupted) is **0,01**, while the probability that a one will be received as zero is **0,05**. Find the probability that:

1. Zero is sent, if zero is received
2. One is sent, if one is received

**My solution**

Since a zero is 5 times more common than 1, the format should look something like 000001 (one way). This means that there's a **5/6** probability that a zero is sent, while **1/6** probability that one is sent through the data stream.

Now, we find the complementary value to figure out the success rate of each bit. Zero bits have **0,01 chance** to be received as one, which means it has **0,99 chance** to go through successfully. Same thing goes for ones, which have **0,95 chance** to go through as one, and 0,05 chance to be transformed to zero.

**1. Zero is sent, if zero is received**

We have 2 in-depended and mutually exclusive events:

1. Zero is sent
2. Zero is received

5/6 * 0,99 (zero is sent and received as zero) / 5/6 * 0,99 + 1/6 * 0,05 (one is sent and received as zero) = 0.99

**1. One is sent, if one is received**

Same logic:

1/6    * 0,95 / 1/6 * 0.95 + 5/6 * 0,01 = 0.95

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the matter visually, consider the following Venn diagram.

[image]

So we have
$$
P\left( {Rx = 0} \right) = B + C = {5 \over 6}{{99} \over {100}} + {1 \over 6}{5 \over {100}} = {{100} \over {120}}
$$
and
$$
P\left( {Rx = 1} \right) = A + D = {5 \over 6}{1 \over {100}} + {1 \over 6}{{95} \over {100}} = {{20} \over {120}}
$$
Note that the Rx probability are te same as the TX, and this is just due to the fact
that the corruption probabilities are taken to have the same ratio.

So, going on to find the probabilities that are requested you have
$$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {Tx = 0|Rx = 0} \right) = {B \over {B + C}} = {{99} \over {100}}  \cr 
  & P\left( {Tx = 1|Rx = 1} \right) = {D \over {A + D}} = {{19} \over {20}} = {{95} \over {100}} \cr} 
$$
which are not too much significant (and might even be misleading)
because of the given corruption ratio as said above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at this before looking at your answers, and I got the same results. But I did not (need to) use the fact that $P(S=0)=5/6$ and $P(S=1)=1/6$: you can simply use conditional probabilities:
$$P(R=0|S=0) = 1 - P(R=1|S=0) = 1-0.01 = 0.99$$
and
$$P(R=1|S=1) = 1 - P(R=0|S=1) = 1-0.05 = 0.95$$
Presumably there may be still other ways to get to result (e.g., using binary trees).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Your solution is slightly more efficient, but the most important thing, is that the results match.